# Center a nested column bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to center the alignment of nested grid in bootstrap. I've been trying a few ways and can't seem to do it right. Here is the code of the nested grid:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="row">
            Row 1, Col 1
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            Row 2, Col 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="row">
            Row 1, Col 2
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            - Row 2, Col 2 +
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share the jsfiddle or live link if possible..thanx

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/su69L3h5/ ? thanx for fiddle hars..

Comment: Please make a small drawing how you want it to look on smaller and equal or larger than `md` screens, that might make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

append a class to internal rows

```
.centerAlign{
    text-align:center;
}

<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="row centerAlign">
        Row 1, Col 2
    </div>
    <div class="row centerAlign">
        - Row 2, Col 2 +
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Align any thing on Center Then Used This Tag Inside CSS:

```
 text-align:center;
```

Here i am align you Div Class on Center Using `<div class="row">`

```css
.row{
    
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="row">
            Row 1, Col 1
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            Row 2, Col 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="row">
            Row 1, Col 2
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            - Row 2, Col 2 +
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Happy to Help .! Thanks